# How to retrieve number from Jason response

Tags: jmeter

I have the request where I'm passing page number.
`https:// †*********/projects?page=1`

Response will be project details with page number.

```
 {
"Firstpage" : "page=1";
"Lastpage"  : "page=10"

}
```

1000 records will be printed in first page. I need to repeat the request untill it's reached page 10.

I tried capturing with following regular expression

`"Firstpage" : "(.*?)"`

This will capture page=1, but I need to loop till it reached page 10.

Comment: Don't really get what you want to achieve. Is that you need to reach page 10 of your data received from server? Why not request /projects?page=10 then?
Please clarify your question.

Comment: I have the first request -https://****************/api/v1/erp/projects?page=1. Which will give the below response   "QueryInfo": {
      "QryName": "Q_QWS_PC_PTE1",
      "resourceURL": "https://************/GetQuery****v2/q/?auth=",
      "CurrentPage": "page=1",
      "FirstPage": "page=1",
      "LastPage": "page=8",
      "Rows": "7055",
      "TotalRows": "1000"
    }

Comment: The response has the number of records  which is "Rows" which is dynamic and everyday the data changes. These records will be pulled based on pagination which has 1000 records in each page.  Every time when i get the request, i need to get the page number from response and i need to loop the request for all the page numbers so that i can get the response for all rows in above example it is 7055 records.

Comment: So you just need to assemble the whole list of results, page by page, whatever the number of pages? Did I get it right?

Comment: yes correct....

Comment: Is it how to loop that you're asking about, or are you wanting to know how to extract `10` from the JSON? You should share your code that does the fetching.

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract the value for the last page and store it into `Lastpage` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter) configured like:

   - Name of created variable: `Lastpage`
   - Regular Expression: `Lastpage"[\s]+:[\s]+"page=(\d+)`
   - Template: `$1$`

     [image]
2. Add [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) to your Test Plan and put the following [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) expression into "Loop Count" field:

   ```
   ${__jexl3(${Lastpage} - 1,)}
   ```

   [image]
3. That's it, you should be able to refer the next page as  `${__jexl3(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx} + 2,)}` where required

   [image]